# "Route Not Found" in console window when Durandal is trying to load first page of app

Tags: durandal

I'm getting "Route not found" in the console window on trying to load an app converted from 1.2 to 2.0.  Is there any way I can debug what route it's trying to find at the point of failure please?  It would be handy if it said, "cannot find route:/viewmodels/wrongfolder/startup" or something!

Please be aware that ALL of this was working perfectly prior to upgrading from 1.2 to 2.0, so it's differences in the Durandal settings that I need to address. No files have been removed or lost or moved, so it's not that things have changed in the app outside of the new versions of scripts being updated by nuget.

main.js and  config.js live in root of "app" folder. Shell.js is in app/viewmodels and shell.html is in app/views. All views/viewmodels are in the relevant folders below the main /app folder.

I have a "config.js" file with routes returned:

```
var routes = [{
    route: 'home',
    moduleId: 'home',
    title: 'Home',
    nav: true
}, {
    route: 'labTool',
    moduleId: 'labTool',
    title: 'Lab Tool',
    nav: true
}];

var startModule = 'labTool';
```

main.js:

```
//specify which plugins to install and their configuration
app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true,
    widget: false
});

app.start().then(function () {
    viewLocator.useConvention();
    router.makeRelative({ moduleId: 'viewmodels' });
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');

    router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
        logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
    };
});
```

Shell.js:

```
    var inEditMode = ko.observable(false); //set edit mode to false at start

    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        router: router,
        inEditMode: inEditMode
    };
    return shell;


    function activate() {
        return datacontext.primeData()
            .then(boot)
            .fail(failedInitialization);
    }

    function boot() {
        logger.log('Application Loaded!', null, system.getModuleId(shell), true);
        router.map(config.routes).buildNavigationModel();
        return router.activate(config.startModule);
    }

    function failedInitialization(error) {
        var msg = 'App initialization failed: ' + error.message;
        logger.logError(msg, error, system.getModuleId(shell), true);
    }
```

Some of the code may still need editing to handle the change from 1.2 to 2.0 but I think I have most of it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem after the upgrade and creating a default route with a route property of '' sorted it for me.

So instead of using your startModule property try setting you labTool route to have a route property of ''.

Comment: This is exactly right. Got help from Rob Eisenberg last night which helpfully explained how the default route works.  Adding the default route cured everything so all is good again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into this, this error can also occur if you have non-ascii characters in the route name.

Not working:

```
{ route: 'Møøse', ... }
```

Working:

```
{ route: 'Moose', title: 'Møøse', ... }
```